# How can I fix Python API encoding to create or save these symbols & # '?

Tags: python, api, encoding, utf-8

Excuse me, I have def create in Python for API use. With any character including symbols can saved or created.

[image]

With encoding like this:

```
text = str(bbas + l).encode('UTF-8')
hash_md5 = hashlib.md5(text).hexdigest()
md5_encode = hash_md5.encode('UTF-8')
hash_sha1 = hashlib.sha1(md5_encode).hexdigest()
location_source = hash_sha1[0:6]
```

But except these symbols & # '
[image]
[image]

How do I fix the code to parse data to accept symbols & # '?
Regards, Fauzi

Comment: `eval()` has nothing to do in processing user input. Use an established and safe format like JSON for it.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters added to the URL should be URL-encoded. Use `urllib.parse.quote` for python3, `urllib.urlencode` for python2.

As mentioned in the comments, best not to use eval() on data received through your API - serialise it with something like JSON instead.

Comment: As mentioned, I used JSON instead method "POST" with 
'Content-Type': 'application/json'.

I tried to convert the symbols at the url by using %26 for &, %23 for # and %22 for ". It works. But it is not recommended for user.